# What is the replacement for labelFunction in Spark DataGrid?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

mx:DataGrid has a property called "labelFunction". I'm migrating my datagrid to Spark, but it doesn't have this property. How should I replace this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [labelFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/gridClasses/GridColumn.html#labelFunction) property on the GridColumn class.

I'll point out, you would have used the same approach w/ the MX DataGrid. The [labelFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html#labelFunction) was a property on the DataGridColumn class; not on the DataGrid.

Comment: Whilst I admit that I was slightly confused at the time of asking the question, I nonetheless contend that the labelFunction on Spark's GridColumn is a replacement for labelFunction on MX's DataGridColumn. There is no replacement for labelFunction on MX's DataGrid. If you want to use a certain labelFunction for all you columns, in MX you just put a labelFunction on the dataGrid. In Spark, you have to specify your labelFunction on each column individually. But hey, it works, thanks.